# laravel 5 custom paginator not working

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

im trying to implement a view like sphinx documentation where you can click on next and previous to navigate between pages. not sure if im using the custom paginator on array right, i cant get page navigation links to display on a view page. this is the code:

```
   public function paginate($array, $perPage, $pageStart=1) {

    $offset = ($pageStart * $perPage) - $perPage;

    return new Paginator(array_slice($array, $offset, $perPage, true), $perPage, $pageStart);
   }

   view()->composer('layouts.book', function($view)
   {
        //some other code
        $pages = [];
        foreach($book->textsection_pages as $textsection) {
            $pages[] = $textsection->alias;
        }
        foreach($book->task_pages as $task) {
            $pages[] = $task->alias;
        }
        foreach($book->tutor_pages as $tutor) {
            $pages[] = $tutor->alias;
        }
        foreach($book->eval_pages as $eval) {
            $pages[] = $eval->alias;
        }

        $chapters = $book->chapters()->orderBy('weight', 'asc')->get();
        $paginated = $this->paginate($pages, 1);
        $view->with(['chapters' => $chapters, 'book' => $book, 'paginated' => $paginated]);

    });
```

and in the view i called `{!! $paginated->render() !!}`, but no navigation link was displayed.

Comment: Have your checked laravel 5 api, Paginator's constructor is `__construct(mixed $items, int $total, int $perPage, int|null $currentPage = null, array $options = array())`

Comment: Yes, i did. its `__construct($items, $perPage, $currentPage = null, array $options = [])`

Comment: Ah, I see it's because you are calling the paginate() method within a closure, which `$this` does not refer to the class.

Comment: ohh i see. how would you call `paginate()` method within a closure?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I handle custom Pagination in my application (Laravel 5.1). I create a partial view `resources/views/partials/pagination.blade.php`

```
@if ($paginator->lastPage() > 1)
<ul id="pagination">
    <li>
    @if ($paginator->currentPage() > 1)
        <a class="prev" href="{{ $paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()-1) }}">Previous</a>
    @else
        <span class="disabled">Previous</span>
    @endif
    </li>

    <li>
    @if ($paginator->currentPage() !== $paginator->lastPage())
        <a class="next" href="{{ $paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()+1) }}" >Next</a>
    @else
        <span class="disabled">Next</span>
    @endif
    </li>
</ul>
@endif
```

In my controller, I pass the usual `$model->paginate(10)` method. Then finally in my view where I want to use the Paginator, `resources/views/list.blade.php` I do this:

```
@foreach ($objects as $object)
    // Here we list the object properties
@endforeach
@include("partials.pagination", ['paginator' => $objects])
```

Comment: hey, you are still using the built in paginator on models. i want a paginator that works on a collection or an array.